How to unfold variable only once in vscode debugger
I am debugging the go code in vscode. The binary tree struct is shown in the left panel as:

The problem is you have to expand two times to get the fields of the variable.
First:

Then:

In Goland, you just need to unfold once to get subfields, like:

It's so weird that I have to expand extra one time to get the subfields in vscode. If the variable is a deep binary tree, a lot of extra lines are shown when I expand them all, and it doesn't look straight.
Is there a way to make it behave like Goland?
Same struct view comparing:
vscode:

Goland:

